# Imported MySQL database to MongoDB - One to Many relationship id's update

Tags: mysql, mongodb, database

I imported my MySQL database to MongoDB using MongoVUE.

First let me make an example of my tables:

```
Table0 = 1,500 entries
Table1 = 120,000 entries
Table2 = 18,000,000 entries

Table0 -> hasMany -> Table1 entries
Table1 -> hasMany -> Table2 entries
```

All tables have a `_id` key now but after the import both tables still have an `id` key from MySQL.

How do I updated table2's keys `table1_id` to match table1's `_id` key? Is it doable using a Mongo query or should I have to write a script for that? (The only language I know is PHP and Javascript/NodeJS)

---

### Update 1

Using user @profesor79 answer I made this query where `table1 = market_item_histories` and `table2 = market_items`

```
db.market_item_histories.aggregate([    
    {
        $lookup: {
            from:"market_items",
            localField: "market_item_id",
            foreignField: "id",
            as: "market_items_docs"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind:"$market_items_docs"
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id:1,
            oldId:"$market_item_id",
            market_item_id:"$market_items_docs._id",
            date:1,
            price:1,
            amount:1,
            created_at:1,
            updated_at:1
        }        
    },
    {
        $out:"marketItemHistories"
    }
])
```

When running that code I get this Error:

```
assert: command failed: {
        "errmsg" : "exception: Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$lookup'",
        "code" : 16436,
        "ok" : 0
} : aggregate failed
Error: command failed: {
        "errmsg" : "exception: Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$lookup'",
        "code" : 16436,
        "ok" : 0
} : aggregate failed
    at Error (<anonymous>)
    at doassert (src/mongo/shell/assert.js:11:14)
    at Function.assert.commandWorked (src/mongo/shell/assert.js:254:5)
    at DBCollection.aggregate (src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1278:12)
    at (shell):1:26
2016-04-29T14:13:48.223+0000 E QUERY    Error: command failed: {
        "errmsg" : "exception: Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$lookup'",
        "code" : 16436,
        "ok" : 0
} : aggregate failed
    at Error (<anonymous>)
    at doassert (src/mongo/shell/assert.js:11:14)
    at Function.assert.commandWorked (src/mongo/shell/assert.js:254:5)
    at DBCollection.aggregate (src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1278:12)
    at (shell):1:26 at src/mongo/shell/assert.js:13
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a nice real life problem.
To get this done we can use aggregation framework and "join" tables, then write results in new collection.
After that the source can be renamed/deleted and our out can be renamed too.
This was done using mongo console.

Please find solution for joining table1 with table0, and use this to perform on others joins.

```
db.table1.aggregate([    
    {
        $lookup:{
            from:"table0",
            localField: "table0_Id", // this is our join source
            foreignField: "id", // this id field in table0 collection
            as: "table0_docs"
            }
    },
    {
        $unwind:"$table0_docs"
        },
    {
        $project:{
            // very important list all fields here
            _id:1,
            data:1,
            oldId:"$table0_Id",
            referenceID:"$table0_docs._id",

            }        
        },
        {
            $out:"newCollectionName"
            }
    ])
```

> AND OUTPUT DOCUMENT

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57234f5de63d33670e521892"),
    "data" : "22",
    "oldId" : 1,
    "referenceID" : ObjectId("57234f33e63d33670e52188e")
}
```

Any comments welcome!

Comment: I will try to use this solution in about an hour or so. I'll let you know if I have any further questions and/or something goes wrong. Thanks.

Comment: I edited my question. I receive an error. Edit: Looks like my mongo is outdated (3.0.7) I need atleast 3.2.

Comment: are you able to upgrade?

Comment: I was able to upgrade. Running the command was successful, will wait until it is processed.